# What can I do legally about a property which constitutes a major fire risk for my property and neighbouring school?

Tags: australia

There is a property out the back of my place full of long grass and [Gorse Bushes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulex) which are taller than any adult. this property sits between the edge of a forest and the back of a couple of properties including my own and the neighbouring school.

Having dealt with Gorse on my own property and seeing just how quickly it burns up and the fact people are just generally idiots/dicks and would be the cause of a fire starting during a fire ban if a fire was to be set in this property or come in from the forest it would make the situation much worse.

the only time this property has ever been treated was well over a decade ago when the CFA tried a controlled burn but lost control, since then there as been no attempt to do anything about this property.

ideally I would like to hire people to come in and rip the ground up so it can be used as sort of a fire defence front (ie, clear any obstacles for firetrucks, allows easy access to water, reduce potential fuel etc.) but I don't know if this property is owned by the local council or privately owned, either way neither one seems to have noticed or care about the danger this property presents.

So I am wondering what I can legally do to deal with this property.

Answer (score 2):

First, property ownership information in Australia is publically available. You can contact your local council or the Land Titles Office in your state or territory to find out who owns it.

Legally, you cannot really do anything to the property without the owners permission. However, since you have by now followed the above step you can now contact the owner and ask their permission. They will either grant it in which case you can proceed with your plan. Or they won't.

If they don't, have a solicitor write them a letter putting them on notice that you consider the state of their property presents an ongoing fire hazard to your life and property and that in the event of an adverse event you will hold them responsible and seek damages. Again, offer to do something about it at your expense. I'm guessing they will either do something themselves or give you permission.

If they don't, you now have a relationship with a solicitor and they can advise you better than we can.